# include rows without references in join result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a users and an activities table. Users get points for their activities and I want to get a list of the top 5 users by points within a certain time period:

```
select top 5 [firstname], [lastname], SUM(user_activities.duration) as points
from      [users]
left join [user_activities] on [users].[id] = [user_activities].[user_id] 
WHERE     [user_activities].[timestamp] >= '2018-03-01'
and       [user_activities].[timestamp] <= '2018-03-31'
group by [firstname], [lastname]
order by [points] desc, [firstname] asc
```

Unfortunately users without activities don't show up. This is because of the where timestamp clauses. Is there some way to include them nonetheless? They would just have 0 points.

Comment: Switch WHERE to AND. (As it is now your left join returns inner join result.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch `WHERE` to `AND`. (As it is now your `left join` returns `inner join` result.)

I.e. the right side table conditions should be in the `ON` clause!

```
select top 5 [firstname], [lastname], SUM(user_activities.duration) as points
from [users] left join [user_activities] on [users].[id] = [user_activities].[user_id] 
  and [user_activities].[timestamp] >= '2018-03-01'
  and [user_activities].[timestamp] <= '2018-03-31'
group by [firstname], [lastname]
order by [points] desc, [firstname] asc
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the WHERE clause into the JOIN

```
SELECT TOP 5
            firstname
            , lastname
        , SUM(ISNULL(user_activities.duration,0)) AS points
FROM
            users
LEFT JOIN   user_activities ON  users.id = user_activities.user_id
                            AND user_activities.timestamp   >= '2018-03-01'
                            AND user_activities.timestamp   <= '2018-03-31'
GROUP BY
            firstname
            , lastname
ORDER BY
            points DESC
            , firstname ASC;
```